# cross validation and hyperparameter tuning for multiple time series

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, boosting, prophet

I have time series data for 2000 products. If I use models like fbprophet or SARIMAX or xgboost then the cross validation needs to be done for 2000 time series data. for a single time series data it takes around 30 mins for cross validation and finding the best parameters. what is the best practice to follow while doing cross validation for multiple time series?